# Best way to periodically query a server and return a specific value in addition to another value

Tags: c#, .net, json

Maybe the title is not good enough, I know. Here is my propblem.

I'm currently writing a class library for a program which handles the new version checks and downloads of the patches.
A dedicated updating framework is no option for me because they mostly are too bloated. I really only want to query the server, check for a new version and if there is a new version download the patch.

In my current setup I have a class which calls the server that returns a json encoded text document (for now, we are going to switch toWebApi2 later). This text document is then deserialized by JSON.NET into a list of the following c# object.

```
/// <summary>Represents a patch.</summary>
/// ToDo: Implement ICompareable and IEquatable
public class Patch
{
    /// <summary>Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="Patch"/> class.</summary>
    /// <param name="version">The version of the patch.</param>
    [JsonConstructor]
    public Patch(string version)
        : this(new Version(version))
    {
    }

    /// <summary>Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="Patch"/> class.</summary>
    /// <param name="version">The version of the patch as string.</param>
    public Patch(Version version)
    {
        this.Version = version;
    }

    /// <summary>Gets the version of the patch.</summary>
    [JsonConverter(typeof(VersionConverter))]
    public Version Version { get; private set; }

    /// <summary>Gets or sets the size of the patch.</summary>
    public long Length { get; set; }

    /// <summary>Gets or sets the primary download uri.</summary>
    public Uri DownloadUri { get; set; }

    /// <summary>Gets or sets the fallback download uri.</summary>
    public Uri FallbackUri { get; set; }
}
```

After deserialization I iterate through said list and check if a new version is available. If there is a new version available the method returns with true. If there is no new version available the method returns with false.

Now I'm puzzled what is the best way to return the version object itself. I could do this with an out parameter, but I'm not sure if this is the best way. Especially since the checking method has to rerun until it returns false (meaning the program is at the latest version).

Could events be a possibility? How about a tuple? Or am I missing something completely?

//edit: For those who are interested, here is the method which I'm talking about.

```
public bool CheckForNewVersion(out Patch newPatch)
{
    string versionFileContents = this.GetVersionFile();

    List<Patch> patches = this.Deserialize(versionFileContents);

    foreach (Patch patch in patches)
    {
        if (patch.Version > this.CurrentVersion)
        {
            newPatch = patch;
            return true;
        }
    }

    newPatch = null;
    return false;
}
```

Comment: out is good, event is good too. I don't have a preference for either, but i often use an event like OnPatchAvailable(Version ver) or something like that.

Comment: What if you have multiple Patch objects which have 2 or more versions different from the default version? If that is a possible case, you might (A) have an `IList<Version>` out parameter or similar, or (B) use an input parameter of the same type which would require passing an existing list object. (It really depends on what would fit better to your code and internal logic). Event (as mentioned by MaxOvrdrv) or a callback delegate (similar to an event, but less versatile) could also be an option.

Comment: Maybe off but why not have the method return List<Patch> rather than Boolean.  Where List<Patch> is only those with newer versions.

Comment: @elgonzo Currently the method returns true and an out parameter with the new version. Then another objects download and install the patch, then the whole thing is repeated until there is no new version available.

I went with a boolean return value because the I just have to check if the return value is true or false before going into more expensive options.

Comment: Okay, but then why is there a foreach loop iterating over a list of Patches in your code? Obviously, one call of *CheckForNewVersion* has to handle multiple Patch objects, not only one. Is it your intention to abort iterating/processing and discard the remaining Patch objects if you encounter a new patch version?

Comment: Yes it is. Since the document/api contains/returns all available patches (since users could have a different version installed) I have to go from the bottom up. I'm not sure How I handle the discarding yet, since calling the server every time is time and resource consuming, so I'll most likely cache the server response or the deserialized list.

Answer (score 0):

You could change the signature of the method to something like this

```
    public IEnumerable<Patch> GetUpdates(string currentClientVersion)
    {
        var updates = new List<Patch>();

        if (currentClientVersion != LatestVersion)
        {
            updates = GetRequiredUpdates(currentClientVersion);
        }

        return updates;
    }
```

This would give you a list of all the updates to apply, or an empty list if the client has the latest version installed.

Answer (score 0):

Unless i'm misinterpreting the question, I would prefer objects to encapsulate the data required and returned. This will allow you to add any new functionality in the future (as this is an API).

```
//What patches are available?
public class PatchCheckOutcome {

     public PatchCheckOutcome(bool newPatchAvailble, List<Patch> availablePatches) {
          NewPatchAvailable = newPatchAvailable;
          AvailablePatches = availablePatches ?? New List<Patch>();
     }

     public bool NewPatchAvailable { get; private set; }
     public List<Patch> AvailablePatches { get; private set; }

}

//Information required to check what patches are available
public class PatchCheckInformation {

     public string CurrentVersion { get; set; }
}



//API method
public PatchCheckOutcome GetAvailablePatches(PatchCheckInformation info);
```

Comment: I see the concept behind this, and it's benefits, but this is not what I'm looking for exactly. As stated in the comments of the original question I'm downloading the patches one after another, so my checking method actually returns after it finds the next higher version. If I'd return multiple patches I'd go in your direction.